# zeromq (zmq) missing messages with c++ publisher and python subscriber

Tags: python, c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I'm not receiving any zeromq messages when using a python subscriber and a c++ publisher.

I setup a test case with the zguide.
I run taskwork2, taskwork2, tasksink2, taskvent. tasksink2 is a publisher and taskwork2 is a subscriber. 
When running all c++ or all python parties all works well. 
When running  tasksink2 in c++ and the rest in python, the final KILL message is not received and the taskwork2 tasks never complete.
When running  tasksink2 in python and the rest in c++, all works well.
Per the missing message guide, I start taskwork2 before tasksink2.

I tried creating simple cases with a c++ publisher sending a test message repeatedly, but python subscribers don't receive any messages.

Any suggestions on a fix or debugging methods?

So far I have only tested this on windows.

Answer (score 1):

### Step No.1: Check ZeroMQ version coherence

Test and publish both C++ and Python side ZeroMQ version number outputs

```
# PYTHON SIDE:
from zmq import zmq_version
zmq_version()
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue.   The c++ components were using zmq 4.0.4 and python was using zmq 2.2.   After upgrading pyzmq to 4.0.4, the problem was resolved.